# Regex to find characters between find underscore and period

Tags: regex

I'm a total newcomer to Regex and wondered how I extract `0090203` from this String:

`/src/test/resources/shopping_invoice/invoice_0090203.txt`

The following gets me everything after the last underscore:

`([^_]+)?\$")`

I'm sure it must be simple :(

Comment: You can use: `\d+(?=\.)`

Comment: there are several ways and it depends on what you consider the granted pattern in such string.. anyway maybe one safe option could be `_(\d+)\.txt$` and grab the capturing group

Comment: Another way: `(?<=/invoice_)[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=/invoice_)[0-9]+
[0-9]+(?=[.][^./]+$)
[0-9]+(?=[.]txt$)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/8AEXNF/1), [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/8AEXNF/2), [regex demo #3](https://regex101.com/r/8AEXNF/3)

The `(?<=/invoice_)[0-9]+` regex matches one or more digits that are immediately preceded with `/invoice_`.

The `[0-9]+(?=[.][^./]+$)` regex matches one or more digits that are immediately followed with `.` and then one or more chars other than `.` and `/` till end of string.

The `[0-9]+(?=[.]txt$)` regex matches one or more digits that are immediately followed with `.` and then `txt` at the end of string.